# VirtualBox 6.1.28 fails to load R0 module (`VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE`) on Windows

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1.28 fails to start a box on Windows with the following error:

```
Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0:
SUP_IOCTL_LDR_OPEN failed (VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE).
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE).
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirtualBox v. 6.1.28 is buggy, use another version (e.g. 6.1.26 or 6.1.32) which you can download from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1

The issue is tracked as https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20694 and was fixed in v. 6.1.32.

Comment: Had the same issue. Downgradeing to 6.1.26 solved the problem :)

Comment: They've released 6.1.30 already :)
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: 6.1.30 still doesn't fix the issue, according to @alhernau.

Comment: Just reinstall using another version. For Linux you can follow the instructions provided in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/703750/1336006). For me 6.1.26 solved the problem as well

Comment: alanextar... They already released 6.1.38 and this issue STILL exists. I don't now if Oracle is addressing this bug or not... I installed the latest VBox on latest Ubuntu and yes reverting to an old version makes this bug go away, but that is not a FIX or even a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround...

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20694

"The Windows Hypervisor-enforced Code Integrity (HVCI) feature rejects the VirtualBox component VMMR0.r0 (*). A workaround is to disable HVCI aka Memory integrity as follows:

On your Windows host, go to Start > Settings > Update & security > Windows Security > Device security > Core isolation details, turn off Memory integrity and reboot the Windows host.

(*) In the Windows Event Log, under Applications and Service Logs\Microsoft\Windows\CodeIntegrity\Operational, an event with ID 3111 ("The file under validation did not meet the hypervisor-protected code integrity (HVCI) policy.") is logged."

Answer (score 1):

Fixed moving to 6.1.26

On Windows 10:

- Uninstall VirtualBox using the control panel "Program and functionalities" tool. **DO NOT RESTART YET.**
- Manually check for the following folders and remove them if they are still there:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\VirtualBox
  ```

  > *Note:* The folders can be in a different place depending where you installed Oracle VirtualBox; make sure to check the correct folder in case you changed the installation directory.
- Go to your `%userprofile%` directory (eg: `C:\users\me`) and delete the folders:

  ```
  .VirtualBox
  VirtualBox VMs
  ```
- Go to RegEdit (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`) and click on `Computer` at the very top.
- Then click on "Edit" > "Search" or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Type `virtualbox` and tick all checkboxes.
- Find the key `Oracle` > `VirtualBox`. It should be in

  ```
  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox
  ```
- Remove the `VirtualBox` key.
- **IMPORTANT: RESTART NOW. Restart your computer!**
- Install VirtualBox again with the new version.

Thanks to: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=82689

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution. You have to open Oracle VM VirtualBox.exe and move into your machine settings, make sure that in Controller: SATA you have only .iso of your machine, if you have something else, delete it, close Oracle VM VirtualBox. In Control panel find programs and features, delete your Oracle VM VirtualBox. Then download Oracle VM VirtualBox again, it's not necessary, which version you will launch but better the latest or the same you had before. After installation check out a capability of your machine, if it works, you may add other .iso back, if it doesn't work, open settings again and Controller: SATA delete all .iso exclude your machine .iso, then launch the machine again.
It works with my virtual machines, if it's not relevant to your occasion, you can try other variants.